# Crash with tableView endUpdates using RATreeView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using the RATreeView component at https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView by Rafał Augustyniak.

Using the posted /Demo code on github:

Add:

```
RADataObject *rdo = [self.data objectAtIndex:0];
[self.treeView expandRowForItem:[rdo.children objectAtIndex:0]];
```

at the bottom of viewWillAppear.

Change the lines of the phone objects to:

```
(void)loadData
{
RADataObject *phone2 = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phone 2" children:nil];
RADataObject *phone3 = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phone 3" children:nil];
RADataObject *phone4 = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phone 4" children:nil];

RADataObject *phone1 = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phone 1" children:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:phone2, phone3, phone4, nil]];

RADataObject *phone = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phones"
children:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:phone1, nil]];
```

(This gives a nested list, where phone -> phone 1 -> phone2, phone3, phone4)

This reproduces the crash that I am having in my app.

It crashes on:

```
(void)expandCellForTreeNode:(RATreeNode *)treeNode withRowAnimation:(RATreeViewRowAnimation)rowAnimation
```

with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS for:

```
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

I've traced through this for a couple of days, and am not sure how to work around this crash (or even why it is happening).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message I get using your code is the following. To reproduce this error, move 
`[self.treeView expandRowForItem:[rdo.children objectAtIndex:0]];`
 to `viewDidAppear`.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (24) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (12), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (24 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

The number of rows has changed to 24, copying existing rows and insert them to the table, but the insertion is not successful.

It seems the thing you want to do is to expand a sub node, you can do that by looking at the implementation of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, because expanding a row is just like clicking a row. To do it manually add the following code.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
RATreeNode *treeNode = [self.treeView treeNodeForIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.treeView expandCellForTreeNode:treeNode];

NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
RATreeNode *treeNode1 = [self.treeView treeNodeForIndexPath:indexPath1];
[self.treeView expandCellForTreeNode:treeNode1];
```

It is just as if you click row 0, and row 1 sequentially. You also need to import this header file.

```
#import "RATreeView+Private.h"
```

Comment: #import "RATreeView+Private.h" -> Xcode eror - "file not found"